# "Cannot add output" crash when I try to enter background in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

I have written code so that when I enter the background and return the camera session should not screw up, but that is not the case. When you return I get the error below:

> 2019-01-29 18:04:57.702967-0500 Proj[2105:617183] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession addOutput:] Cannot add output  to capture session

The problematic code is below:

```
    func notificationCenter() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification , object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(openedAgain), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func openedAgain() {
    setupCamera() //This is your function that contains the setup for your camera.
}

@objc func willResignActive() {
    print("Entered background")
    let inputs = captureSession.inputs
    for oldInput:AVCaptureInput in inputs {
        captureSession.removeInput(oldInput)
    }
}
```

The method here is called in `viewdidload`

**Note**: the camera session seems to still be working when you return, even with the error, as I can see what the cam sees but I cannot do anything other than move cam around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1387325-addoutput?language=objc)

> addOutput:This method throws an exception when invoked and canAddOutput(_:) returns false.

so before you add any output you have to check `canAddOutput` same with adding inputs `canAddInput`

regarding your issue you need to use `captureSession.stopRunning()` when resigning and `captureSession.startRunning()` when being active

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(stopTheSession), name: UIApplication.applicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(startTheSession), name: UIApplication.applicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

Comment: So shoudl I do teh following inside of teh setupInputOutput method which I call in viewdidload?:::             if captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput!) {
                captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
            }

Comment: I do the same for video

Comment: When I did so I just get a weird thing where when I return the capture sessions does not run so teh screen is black, and then after a bit of touching ot just crashes\